# Проприетарные драйвера ATI/AMD в Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd, radeon

Не устанавливается драйвер штатными средствами системы. Точнее устанавливается, но не работает.
Выдает такую ошибку:

[image]

Если перезагрузить после установки, то рабочую среду не открывает толком, только рабочий стол без остальных элементов.

Железо: AMD A4-4300M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2.

Чего ему надо?

[Вывод установки драйвера через терминал](https://yadi.sk/i/2fQrzqJucrzdC).
[xorg.conf](https://yadi.sk/d/XyXv36oKcrzgj).

Инфо о системе:

[image]

ОС 64-битная, а драйвер, судя по тому, что пишется в процессе установки, - 32 бит. Это так должно быть? Я не айтишник, но мне кажется, что драйвер тоже 64 должен быть.

Comment: Похоже проблема в том, что новые драйвера не поддерживают карты младше пятой ветки. Но странно то, что в июне все работало.
Попробую поставить lеgacy драйвер.

Comment: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-16.04-Dropping-fglrx амдшники давно хотели выбросить поддержку старых карт для новых версий XServer

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

Похоже проблема в том, что новые драйвера не поддерживают карты младше пятой ветки. Но странно то, что в июне все работало. Попробую поставить lеgacy драйвер.